# What do I do at the Lighthouse?

Tags: candy-box-2

I keep going to the Lighthouse and finding nothing to do. Can someone tell me what I can do there? I've clicked everywhere but I get nothing.

Answer (score 1):

get to the castle.  once you are there go down the stairs.  ask the dragon for candies, then go back and there is a new option to talk.  solve the puzzle and you will get something important

Comment: What's the something important?

Answer (score -1):

The only thing of note to be found at the Lighthouse is the Cyclops. There are a number of questions you can ask the Cyclops, and eventually he will give you something if you solve a puzzle. See the Candy Box 2 [wiki](http://candybox2.gamepedia.com/The_Cyclops) for more.